# Counting occurrences of a field based on another field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count a certain field and how much it occurs based on a date. For example, I have a reputation field that I need counted, so if there is 5 reputation points that were individually  submitted on 12/14/2014, how would I get the total amount and not just 5 rows?

This is an example of what I am trying to do (if it helps explain it better)

```
            'ID'        => 1,
            'rep'     => 'SK01',
            '25/11/14'    => '5',
            '26/11/14'    => '23',
            '27/11/14'    => '3',
            '28/11/14'    => '87',
            '29/11/14'    => '4',
            '01/12/14'    => '45',
            '02/12/14'    => '145',
```

On today [ 2014-12-08 09:53:27 ] there were 1 for AH05 (I'm just getting a repeat of that however many times it is in table) Here is the SQL also if that helps

```
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) as TotalValueCount, DATE(date_created) AS thedate
    FROM wp_rg_lead INNER JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail ON wp_rg_lead.id = wp_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
    WHERE wp_rg_lead.form_id = '47' AND date_created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
    AND NOW() AND field_number = '18' GROUP BY value, date_created
```

Comment: Are the reputations stored as ints or strings?

Answer (score 0):

You would do a `group by` query, but the results would be in *rows*, not *columns*:

```
select rep, date, count(*)
from table t
group by rep, date;
```

If, for some reason, you really *have to* have the values in columns, I would suggest doing it at the application layer.  Otherwise, Google "MySQL dynamic pivot" to get ideas on what to do.

Comment: I just need to count how many times a reputation occurs for a value based on the date, for instance, if a site got 10 points in a day, I would need it to display total points for today: 10 instead of listing each row on a page 10 times. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user2101411 . . . Yes, that is what this query does.  The value for each date goes on a separate row.

Comment: I need to count the total amount of rows returned for rep points based on the date, but I'm just getting ten rows displayed on a page rather than the total count..

Comment: On today [ 2014-12-09 ] there were 1 for AR02

There is more than one for this, but all I can get displayed is one.

Comment: @user2101411 . . . My guess is that you don't want `id` in the output.